# Vb.Net Scaling with a maximum increase and back again

Tags: vb.net

I’m trying to scale controls on a form Width 3x Height 2.5x larger on maximize then return them to normal on form normalizing. These %'s are not based on the actual % increase of the form itself (controls sometimes just got too big depending on form size).

On maximize looks like:
Control.Scale(3, 2.5)

But, when you normalize:
Control.Scale(-3, -2.5)

It 0,0’s the results. Is there a better way to do this? I've been banging my head on the keyboard for a while now.

Full code below:

```
Public Class TestMainMenu
    Dim intStaticWidth As Integer = 263         'Form design WIDTH
    Dim intStaticHeight As Integer = 157        'Form design Height
    Dim intFontSize As Integer = 8              'Default font size
    Dim intBaseHeight As Integer = 157          'Used for FONT scaling
    '--------
    Dim dblWidthPercent As Double              'Percentage of increase/decrease
    Dim dblHeightPercent As Double             'Percentage of increase/decrease

    Dim blnFormLoad As Boolean = True
    Dim blnDoOnce As Boolean = True             'Once per form flag

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.Width = intStaticWidth
        Me.Height = intStaticHeight
        blnFormLoad = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub FormResize(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
        If blnFormLoad = True Then Exit Sub

        Dim ResizeRatio As SizeF
        Select Case Me.WindowState
            Case FormWindowState.Maximized

                If blnDoOnce = True Then
                    dblWidthPercent = Me.Width / intStaticWidth
                    dblHeightPercent = Me.Height / intStaticHeight
                    blnDoOnce = False
                    If dblWidthPercent > 3 Then
                        If dblWidthPercent > 3 Then
                            dblHeightPercent = (3 * dblHeightPercent) / dblWidthPercent
                        End If

                        dblWidthPercent = 3
                    End If
                End If

                If dblWidthPercent < 1 Then dblWidthPercent = (Math.Abs(dblWidthPercent) * -1)
                If dblHeightPercent < 1 Then dblHeightPercent = (Math.Abs(dblHeightPercent) * -1)

                ResizeRatio = New SizeF((dblWidthPercent), (dblHeightPercent))
            Case FormWindowState.Minimized

            Case FormWindowState.Normal
                If dblWidthPercent > 1 Then dblWidthPercent = (Math.Abs(dblWidthPercent) * -1)
                If dblHeightPercent > 1 Then dblHeightPercent = (Math.Abs(dblHeightPercent) * -1)

                ResizeRatio = New SizeF((dblWidthPercent), (dblHeightPercent))
            Case Else
        End Select

        For Each Control In Me.Controls
            ResizeControl(Control, ResizeRatio)
        Next
        blnFormLoad = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub ResizeControl(ByVal objControl As Control, ByVal ResizeRatio As SizeF)
        Dim dblPercent As Double
        'Reset
        intFontSize = 8

        objControl.Scale(ResizeRatio)

        Select Case Me.WindowState
            Case FormWindowState.Maximized
                dblPercent = Me.Height / intBaseHeight
                If dblPercent > 3 Then dblPercent = 3
                If dblPercent < 1 Then
                    intFontSize = (intFontSize * dblPercent) + intFontSize
                Else
                    intFontSize = (intFontSize * dblPercent)
                End If
                objControl.Font = New Font("", intFontSize, FontStyle.Regular)
            Case FormWindowState.Minimized
            Case FormWindowState.Normal
                objControl.Font = New Font("", intFontSize, FontStyle.Regular)
            Case Else
        End Select

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        End
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of scaling by the same magnitude but negative, you want to scale by the reciprocal of your original scaling factor. So instead of -2.5 and -3, you want (1/2.5) and (1/3), or 0.4 and .333333... respectively.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't catch that... I owe you thanks!